# wso2iot 3.1.0 error acces devicemgt

Tags: device, wso2, wso2-iot

I have installed the WSO2 IoT Server 3.1.0 by following the installation guide. But when I want to access to `https://myip:9443/devicemgt/`, I enter my login and then SETTING UP YOUR ENVIRONMENT start charging.

> After few minutes Ops... it seems something went wrong.
>   Refresh the page to retry.

appears on the screen.

I can't access to my devicemgt, anyone have a idea?

Answer (score 0):

The error could be due to SSL handshake issues with your machine. Therefore the best way to set up WSO2 IoT server 3.1.0 on your machine is to run the change-ip.sh [script](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Configuring+the+IP+or+Hostname#ConfiguringtheIPorHostname-ConfiguringtheIPorhostnameusingthescript). Please follow only "Configuring the IP or hostname using the script".

Comment: I do "configuring the ip or hostname using the script" but nothing change. After enter my login in "https://10.0.240.35:9443/devicemgt/login?RelayState=%2F&SSOAuthSessionID=CD3F547082F668B8C03851C6162E3297&commonAuthCallerPath=%2Fsamlsso&forceAuth=false&passiveAuth=false&tenantDomain=carbon.super&sessionDataKey=0f5c313d-bd48-4ca7-a608-773ad94ba2dc&relyingParty=devicemgt&type=samlsso&sp=devicemgt&isSaaSApp=true&authenticators=BasicAuthenticator:LOCAL"
I m redirected to "https://10.0.240.35:9443/devicemgt/welcome" and "SETTING UP YOUR ENVIRONMENT" start charging but with an error

Comment: Can you please follow these steps to enable debug logs? Go to the IOT_HOME/conf/log4j.properties file. 
Uncomment the following (#log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG #log4j.logger.feign=DEBUG) 
Comment the following 
(log4j.category.org.apache.synapse=WARN) 
Then restart the IoT server and try to login to the devicemgt application. And check the log file in IoT_Home/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log and attach the error.

Comment: I that normal that i have "#log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.wire=DEBUG" and not "#log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG" (i have a n before http) ?

Comment: I have one error in my log:
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-10-17 15:22:09,328] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor} -  Authentication failed. Please check your username/password {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.interceptors.auth.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor}

Comment: Ok so now i have acces to "https://10.0.240.35/9443/devicemgt" but i have an 500 error: An Error Occurred!
HTTP Status : 500

org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.integration.client.exception.APIMClientOAuthException: failed to retrieve oauth token using jwt

Comment: I think the reason for this issue is SSL handshake failure. This might occur when there is a hostname pointed to 10.0.240.35 or machine name is pointed to the same.
Can please check the /etc/hosts file to make sure that there is no hostname is pointed to 10.0.245.35?

Comment: Ok so that my /etc/hosts, i don't really understand what you ask for (im a beginner):

127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
# --- BEGIN PVE ---
10.0.240.35 wso2
# --- END PVE ---

Comment: You have to remove the (10.0.240.35 wso2) from /etc/hosts and restart the server. And if it does not solve your issue, please enable debug logs as mentioned in the second comment and send the IoT_Home/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log file to geeth(at)wso2(dot)com email.